# how to remove the content together with the html tag using python if it contains some strings

Tags: html, python-2.7, tags

I am currently processing some data in the format of html. The format of the files are more or less like this (do bear in mind that I have already deleted most of the contents for the sake of simplicity showing the code online):

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>some header here</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<P>Some contents that I don't want</P>
<PRE>                                 THE HITCHER
                       A film review by Mark R. Leeper
                        Copyright 1987 Mark R. Leeper</PRE>



<P>// some body paragraphs that I need</P>



<P> //some body paragraphs that I need</P>



<PRE>tags that I don't want</PRE>
<HR><P CLASS=flush><SMALL>tags that I don't want</SMALL></P>
<P ALIGN=CENTER>tags that I don't want</A></P>
</P></BODY></HTML>
```

I only want to get the part marked as `<P> //some body paragraphs that I need</P>` and read into python program as string. Yet I found it hard to do. Can any one help me with it?

If doing so is not easy, at least tell me how to get rid of the entire tag if it contains some substrings. Say I want to get rid of the tag (from the begin of the tag to the end of the tag including the content, in this case, is this line

```
<PRE>                                 THE HITCHER
                       A film review by Mark R. Leeper
                        Copyright 1987 Mark R. Leeper</PRE>
```

) containing the keyword "Copyright".

For whom might concern, the data is from IMDB database, I downloaded from Cornell University's website.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I am thinking about using regular expression to locate the keyword and search for the nearest block of start and closing block of tags, yet only to find it is very hard to do. Maybe it is just I am not that familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: my answer below can help pull out the lines from the HTML given. Then you can use them however you would like.

Comment: I'll try that out. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You will need two librarys to pull this off. One to get the page conetents from the internet, `requests`. Then another to parse the HTML content, `BeautifulSoup.`  The code below goes out to an example website with basic HTML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("http://dataquestio.github.io/web-scraping-pages/simple.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print "Formated HTML"
print "*****************"
print soup.prettify()
print "*****************"
p_list=soup.find_all('p')

print p_list
```

For python 3 you will need to change the print functions to the python 3 format such as: 
 `print p_list` to `print(p_list)`.

---

Per the question in the comment below.

You can read data from local HTML files without using the request method. This is done by simply opening the file and reading the data into a variable for beautiful soup to play with. Remember to change the file name inside of the open function.

```
with open('test.html', 'r') as f:
    read_data = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(read_data, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Does the content within the requests.get() method has to be a link? I am dealing with local html files. That is, I read them inside the python program jus like reading a txt, and then do some modifications.

Comment: Oh that is easier I believe. Let me run it and make sure I give you code with no errors. One moment.